# change name of domain in admin Django CMS

Tags: python, django, django-cms

always that I create a new project in django-CMS, when I go to the admin I see that

[image]

It is posible to change the `example.com` for other name? How to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to change the name under Sites in your admin panel (usually under `/admin/sites/site/`)

More info about [Sites](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/sites/).